# reduce div-width to its content width or to the width of content above/below

Tags: html, css

If you would take a look at this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/v5GXT/1/

```
<div class="text">
    <div id="image">this is an image with unknown width</div>
    This is some text above,This is some text above,This is some text above,This is some text above,This is some text above,This is some text above,
    <div class="code">special content</div>
    and this is some text below,and this is some text below,and this is some text below,and this is some text below,and this is some text below,
</div>
```

Css:

```
.text{
    color:red;
    text-align:justify;
    margin-top:20px;
}

.code{
    border:1px solid blue;
    border-left:10px solid #ccc;
    background:#eee;
    padding:5px;
    margin:5px;
}
.code:before{
    display:block;
    font-size:80%;
    font-style:italic;
    content:"Example:";
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

#image{
    float:right;
    border:2px solid red;
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    margin-left:40px;
}
```

I want the blue div box (special content) to be the same width as the text above/below, or the width of its content, whatever is easier. Why at all is this div as width as the screen?

Any suggestions what's the best way?

Edit1:
easy solution with overflow:
http://jsfiddle.net/v5GXT/6/

```
.code{
    border:1px solid blue;
    border-left:10px solid #ccc;
    background:#eee;
    padding:5px;
    margin:5px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: add  display:inline-block; to your .code class

Comment: Your question is misleading, The title says `reduce div-width to content width` but you also mentioned that `div box to be the same width as the text above/below`. These are completely different.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I changed that

Comment: @user3304232 Thus, I'll respectfully delete my answer.

Comment: Why did you delete your answer, that showed exactly what I wanted to have and was a perfect answer?

Comment: @user3304232 Sorry, I thought that I misunderstood the question as you accepted the other answer. Didn't check your update.

Comment: Yes both answers shows me something new, good to learn from :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the blue div box (special content) to be the same width as the
>   text above/below

You could add [`overflow-x: hidden;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x) to the `.code` div element to hide the horizontal overflow as follows:

```css
.code {
    border:1px solid blue;
    border-left:10px solid #ccc;
    background:#eee;
    padding:5px; margin:5px;

    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v5GXT/6/)**.

Answer (score 3):

So many different ways to do it, this is one of the simplest ones:

Enclose `.code` in a block level `div` and make the `.code` an `inline-block`

HTML:

```
<div class="codeContainer">
    <div class="code">special content</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.codeContainer {
    display: block;
}

.code {
    display:inline-block;
    width:auto;
    border:1px solid blue;
    border-left:10px solid #ccc;
    background:#eee;
    padding:5px;
    margin:5px;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/v5GXT/13/

Answer (score 1):

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cocoa_beans/v5GXT/20/)

css change

```
.code{
margin: 5px 190px 0 0;
}
```